# fetch unable to get response from json server API endpoint

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch, expo, json-server

json server is up and running..API response from Browser GET request is working fine.. but from fetch i always got error "Network Request Failed" ... this code is for react-native on expo environment
i also tried by replacing localhost with corresponding ip.. still didn't work for me.. where am i getting stucked?

#base url

```
export const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3002/";
```

fetchPosts reducer

```
return fetch(baseUrl + "posts")
    .then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error(
            "Error " + response.status + ": " + response.statusText
          );
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        var errmess = new Error(error.message);
        throw errmess;
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((posts) => dispatch(addPosts(posts)))
    .catch((error) => dispatch(postsFailed(error.message)));
```

logger output in console

```
action POSTS_LOADING @ 17:09:00.842
 prev state Object {
  "highlights": Object {
    "errMess": null,
    "highlights": Array [],
    "isLoading": true,
  },
  "posts": Object {
    "errMess": "Network request failed",
    "isLoading": false,
    "posts": Array [],
  },
}
 action     Object {
  "type": "POSTS_LOADING",
}
 next state Object {
  "highlights": Object {
    "errMess": null,
    "highlights": Array [],
    "isLoading": true,
  },
  "posts": Object {
    "errMess": null,
    "isLoading": true,
    "posts": Array [],
  },
}
 action POSTS_FAILED @ 17:09:00.928
 prev state Object {
  "highlights": Object {
    "errMess": null,
    "highlights": Array [],
    "isLoading": true,
  },
  "posts": Object {
    "errMess": null,
    "isLoading": true,
    "posts": Array [],
  },
}
 action     Object {
  "payload": "Network request failed",
  "type": "POSTS_FAILED",
}
 next state Object {
  "highlights": Object {
    "errMess": null,
    "highlights": Array [],
    "isLoading": true,
  },
  "posts": Object {
    "errMess": "Network request failed",
    "isLoading": false,
    "posts": Array [],
  },
}
```

Comment: can you try with https

Comment: tried ..no luck :(

Comment: using android or ios device?

Comment: i am using android device.. i tried axios too... same problem

Comment: check by replacing your IP address with localhost

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: i created nodejs server and direct the url to end point still the get request is not reached to api.. when called through browser and postman ...server is triggered but.. from fetch and axios,  server does not get any request... i may be missing critical thing.. but am unable to find..